# Npm publish is just hung with no output

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying to publish a package that I made. Here is a link to the files [Github Repo](https://github.com/stevekanger/scrollpro). For some reason it is just hung. When I do `npm publish` I just get a cursor. There is no errors or output of any kind. I have tried doing an `npm login` and also `npm adduser` both have me logged in successfully. So I did `npm publish --verbose` and here is the output.

```
PS D:\Development\Projects\scrollpro\package> npm publish --verbose
npm verb cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
npm info using npm@9.4.0
npm info using node@v19.6.0
npm verb title npm publish
npm verb argv "publish" "--loglevel" "verbose"
npm verb logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\Wamo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-18T03_59_42_589Z-
npm verb logfile C:\Users\Wamo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-18T03_59_42_589Z-debug-0.log
npm verb publish [ '.' ]
```

and here is the contents of the log file:

```
0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@9.4.0
2 info using node@v19.6.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 1ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 1ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:D:\Development\Projects\scrollpro\package\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Wamo\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Wamo\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load Completed in 6ms
17 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 6ms
18 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 0ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
20 verbose title npm publish
21 verbose argv "publish" "--loglevel" "verbose"
22 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
23 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms
24 timing npm:load:display Completed in 5ms
25 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\Wamo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-18T03_59_42_589Z-
26 verbose logfile C:\Users\Wamo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-18T03_59_42_589Z-debug-0.log
27 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 4ms
28 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
29 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
30 timing npm:load Completed in 18ms
31 verbose publish [ '.' ]
32 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 2 files
33 silly logfile done cleaning log files
```

I don't see any errors here. And I am just stuck and I have no idea what is going on.

I have other packages that I have published in the past so I went to one of them and changed the version and tried publishing it and that worked just fine. So then I just created a blank package and tried to publish that which worked just fine. So I have no idea what is going on. The package I'm trying to publish is a little larger but still isn't that big but I figured maybe it would take a little longer so I let it sit for an hour and still nothing. Maybe there is something small I am missing here.

Any help here would really be appreciated because this is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was apparently the prepare statement in `package.json`. I was running `npm run build` in that statement and the build script is `tsc --project tsconfig.build.json`. In my `tsconfig.json` file I am setting `watch: true`. This was apparently causing a continuous running build script not allowing the actual publishing part to happen. So I removed the `watch: true` from my my config and just put the `-w` flag in the `package.json` build script. Then in my prepare script I am just doing the build without the watch flag and it works now. Here is how the scripts look in the revised `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "jest",
  "clean": "tsc --build --clean",
  "build": "tsc --project tsconfig.build.json -w",
  "prepare": "tsc --project tsconfig.build.json"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

1 - Check .gitignore and .npmignore files for unintentionally ignored files.

2 - Verify the name, version, main of your package.json.

3 - Exclude unnecessary or large files using .npmignore.

4 - Clear the npm cache with
`npm cache clean --force` and try publishing again.

5 - Update npm and Node.js to their latest stable versions.

This is the docs, https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-publish